# What is the equivalent of skiprow of Pandas in Swift TabularData framework?

Tags: python-3.x, swift, dataframe, data-analysis

I am working with the following CSV data source. The headers starts from 3rd row so I want to skip the first 2 rows while loading CSV data so as to get the header. There is skiprow option in Pandas and I am wondering what would be the equivalent in Swift TabularData framework ?

```
import Foundation

import TabularData

let options = CSVReadingOptions(

hasHeaderRow: false,

nilEncodings: ["","nil"],

ignoresEmptyLines: true

)

let dataPath = "
https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/saipe/datasets/time-series/model-tables/irs.csv"

var dataFrame = try! DataFrame(contentsOfCSVFile: URL(string: dataPath)!, rows: 0..<15, options: options)

print (dataFrame.description)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've  been pondering a similar  question.   Just found
MLDataTable is a useful data structure for managing tabular data. It has most of the functionalities of the Panda library, thereby making it the Panda for iOS and macOS Developers.
https://n-cryptech.com/mldatatable-the-panda-for-ios-developers/

WWDC presentation https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/10100/

Comment: hmmm, after reading  about it...  I'd  say no,  no  it's not  like a  time series  framework  at all.